# Error in compilation of program using gcc

Tags: nasm

While compiling my nasm programm, the command `nasm -felf prgname.asm` works fine but when i use the gcc command `gcc -o prgname prgname.o driver.c asm_io.o` it gives me an error

```
file format not recognized; treating as linker script
/usr/bin/ld:asm_io.o:1: syntax error
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I do not understand this error. Has it to do something with my system architecture?

Comment: From where did you get asm_io.o? How was it compiled?

Comment: what `file asm_io.o` gives you?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error output, it's not your `prgname.o` file that's causing the issue but the `asm_io.o` one. As per the output:

```
file format not recognized; treating as linker script
/usr/bin/ld:asm_io.o:1: syntax error
```

you can see that it's treating *some* file as a textual linker script and then complaining about a syntax error in `asm_io.o`.

Since you tend to get syntax errors from *textual* source code rather than *binary* object files, it's a fairly safe bet that the file being treated as a linker script is the `asm_io.o` one.

---

So you should probably concentrate your efforts there. The first thing to do is to check both files to see what type they are:

```
file prgname.o asm_io.o
```

I'm including the first not because I think it's wrong but because, if it's right, it'll give an indication of what the second one *should* be.

You could also leave `asm_io.o` out of the compilation command altogether. You'll probably get `unresolved symbol` errors but it'll at least prove which file is causing the problem.

Once you've established the problem *is* `asm_io.o`, you'll need to rebuild that (assuming you have source) with the correct options.